# Pruning old versions in a p2 repository

Tags: p2, b3

We have an internal framework which we publish to downstream developers via a p2 repository. We currently build the p2 repository with Tycho and add to the old repository with the `mirror` goal of `tycho-p2-repository-plugin`. This works well.

We want to keep a reasonable large number of "old" versions of the features and plug-ins in the repository to avoid invalidating the target platforms used by the developers, but we also want to avoid that the repository grows beyond reason, so we want to "prune" the oldest versions of the features and plug-ins every now and then.

But how do we do that? I can see a number of possible solutions, but before I try anything, I wondered if anybody else have tried this first.

My two suggestions are:

- b3
- mirror with a filter (but which filter?)

It would be a bonus, if the "pruning" can be run from Tycho/Maven, but that is not a hard requirement as it stands.

Comment: I have no problems when people downvote my questions and answers... but please leave a comment on why the question or answer was downvoted!